# Javascript window positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, window

I have this javascript social locker that works inside a window and I am having trouble when testing it on different screens for responsive (like mobile and etc) because the window changes position. So far I know that this part of the code affects the positioning but I don't know how.

This is the CSS:

```
 #gatewaydiv
    {
    max-width: 15em;
    height: 6em;
    padding: 9em;
    position: absolute;
    display:none;
    background-color:#0e0f0f;

    text-align:center;
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    opacity:0.9;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: -10%;
 }
```

And this is the Javascript window:

```
function setupgateway()
{
var Left = $(window).width() /2.6;
Left = Left - $('#gatewaydiv').width() / 2;

var Top = $(window).height()/2;
Top = Top - $('#gatewaydiv').height()/6;

$('#gatewaydiv').css('top', Top+'px').css('left', Left+'px').css('display', 'inline');
```

If someone can please explain me how does this javascript window code behaves and how can I get it right to work on all devices?

I have read a lot of similar questions but haven't found my answer because the code is quite different, nor this is a pop-up window and I am no javascript expert, to be honest.
[You can see the live version here](http://proyectoswifi.x10host.com/Test1/)

Thank you!

Comment: did you try to center #gatewaydiv (Vertically and Horizontally) using CSS?

Comment: @ Xahed Kamal 
Yes, I have:
 @media (max-width: 768px) {
       #gatewaydiv {
        margin: auto;
        }
But it doesn't make almost any diference.

Comment: Okay. Most of the time i use CSS to center a div vertically and horizontally. Giving you that as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make any element centered (Vertically and Horizontally) using below CSS. For example -

```
#gatewaydiv{
    position:absolute;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translatey(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translatey(-50%);
    -o-transform: translatey(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-50%);
    transform: translatey(-50%);
 }
```

Remember, you'll have to remove `margin-top:-10%` and also disable/remove the Javascript.

Also, replace this line -

```
$('#gatewaydiv').css('top', Top+'px').css('left', Left+'px').css('display', 'inline');
```

By this line -

```
$('#gatewaydiv').css('display', 'inline');
```

Comment: Thank you! This is definitely helping but not centering it 100%. How do I disable just that particular part of the Javascript without messing with the whole?

Comment: Just disable this line -- $('#gatewaydiv').css('top', Top+'px').css('left', Left+'px').css('display', 'inline');  .....  Use // (double slash) to turn the code into a comment. If you disable this line, you'll have absolute centered div

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', setupgateway);
window.addEventListener('scroll', setupgateway);
```